# how to make UIViewAnimation continuous even after view disappears/reappears

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

Im using the glowingButton effect on one of my buttons, and I want this effect to be continuous even after the view disappears, meaning throughout the run-time of the application. Here is the logic for the animation:

```
 // Creates a glow effect in the button by setting its layer shadow properties
    func startGlowWithCGColor (growColor:CGColor) {
        self.layer.shadowColor = growColor
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false

        // Autoreverse, Repeat and allow user interaction.
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse |                                                         UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat
            | UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction,
            animations: { () -> Void in
                // Make it a 15% bigger
                self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.15, 1.15)
            }) { (Bool) -> Void in
                // Return to original size
                self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
                self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
        }
    }

    // Removes the animation
    func stopGlow () {
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
        self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
```

How do I make it continuous?

Comment: where is your button located in view hierachy

Comment: on top of all other views @muku

Comment: Why would it need to be continuous? Why not attempt to store the last time/position and reinitialise when the view is returned to?

Comment: how would i do this? @AppDevGuy

Comment: The first question seems more relevant - why would you want the button to animate continuous in the background if the view is not present?

Comment: so when the view appears its still going @AppDevGuy

Comment: Did you end up resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Call your `startGlowWithCGColor` function in the viewWillAppear function:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.startGlowWithCGColor(growColor)
}
```

This will then trigger the animated button to load on view reappearing, and it will animate until you tell it too stop with your `stop` function.